# Config JNDI from web interface

Tags: jboss, jndi

Is there any way to specify jndi resource through JBoss AS7 admin interface?
I have been looking around, but was unfortunate to find anything like that.

Comment: Login to admin console--> Go to Container|Naming tab. What do you see here?

Comment: I see JNDI Bindings, but i can't rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

Open the Create Datasource Wizard->Profile->Datasource->Add->
Here you will be able to enter datasource name and JNDI name into the Create Datasource wizard

Hope it helps!

Comment: Use this way for to create DataSource, but i would like add JNDI Bindings from web console